# What is the difference between Architectural drivers/factors and architectural significant requirements

Tags: architecture, requirements

I need to be able to explain the terms: architectural factor, architectural driver and architectural significant requirement. i found out that an architectural factor/driver are the same (correct me if i'm wrong).
but when i look up their definitions i get the following explanation:

**architectural driver:**
Architectural drivers are formally defined as the set of requirements that have significant influence over your architecture.

**architecturally significant requirements:**
architecturally significant requirements are those requirements that play an important role in determining the architecture of the system.

it seems to me both of them are requirements that have influence your architecture, however in the book of larman they are clearly introduced as 2 different things.

so can anyone tell me the exact difference between Architectural drivers/factors and architectural significant requirements

Answer (score 0):

Good question! They are indeed confusing. I can add this: the way I see it is that among all requirements gathered for a project, only certain ones will achieve status of ASR once the develop-part-of-the-architecture-then-test cycle goes a few rounds and the picture becomes clearer.

Edit: On slide 18 [here](https://cs.gmu.edu/~rpettit/files/lectures/443-ASRs.pdf), it says the following:

```
Architecture drivers presentation
– Briefing by the architect on the driving business and quality attribute requirements: the ASRs.
```

To me that indicates that they could be seen as equivalent.